# PHP try catch block does not catch

Tags: php, file, exception, try-catch

I would like to open a file in PHP and the first thing I do is a check to see if it exists. Because of this I'm adding it to a a try catch block, so the script does not collapse. If the file does not exist the script should stop.
The code below is giving an error message `the file could not be opened`.

(The file does not exist, for testing reasons)

```
    try
    {
        $file_handle = fopen("uploads/".$filename."","r");
    }
    catch (Exception $hi)
    {
        die("Fehler");
    }
```

This is the error displayed in my browser:

> Warning: fopen(uploads/Testdatensatz_Bewerbungenn.csv): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in [...]\bewerbungToDB.php on line
>   11

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's not an exception. It's a PHP warning. Try/catch is for catching exceptions only. If you want to "catch" that error you should check the value of `$file_handle` and if it is false throw an exception.

```
try
{
    $file_handle = @fopen("uploads/".$filename."","r");
    if (!$file_handle) {
         throw new Exception('Failed to open uploaded file');
    }
}
catch (Exception $hi)
{
    die("Fehler");
}
```

Comment: `echo "Error " . $hi->getMessage();` ;-) get the *real* reason